# Custom Common Input Component - Validation Errors not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to write up a common input component for Material Angular, so I don't have to duplicate 20 lines of HTML code for every single field. But I am having issues getting the `mat-error` to show the validation message.

So this is the code I had in `MyFormComponent`:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" hintLabel="Max 10 characters">
  
    <mat-label> Name Old (works) </mat-label>
    
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nameOld" />

    <mat-hint align="end">the/10</mat-hint>

    <mat-error *ngIf=" (formModal.get('nameOld').dirty || formModal.get('nameOld').touched) &&
        formModal.get('nameOld').errors && formModal.get('nameOld').errors['required'] ">
      Name Old is required.
    </mat-error>
      
  </mat-form-field>
  
</div>
```

Now I've moved this to a custom component `CommonInputComponent` as the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" hintLabel="Max 10 characters">
    <mat-label>{{ fieldInfo.label }}</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [type]="fieldInfo.type"
      [placeholder]="fieldInfo.placeholder"
      [value]="value"
      (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />

    <mat-hint align="end">{{ ngControl.value?.length || 0 }}/10</mat-hint>

    <mat-error
      *ngIf="
        (ngControl.dirty || ngControl.touched) &&
        ngControl.errors &&
        ngControl.errors['required']
      "
      >Name is required.</mat-error
    >
  </mat-form-field>

  <pre>{{ ngControl.errors | json }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ { dirty: ngControl.dirty, touched: ngControl.touched } | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

and then I try to use it in my Form `MyFormComponent` as:

```
<app-common-input
  formControlName="name"
  [fieldInfo]="{ label: 'name', name: 'name', type: 'text' }"
></app-common-input>
```

All the bindings seem to work fine, the properties are updated across both the parent and child components, but the only issue I am facing is that `mat-error` doesn't seem to work as it did in the previous example.

What I am expecting in both fields below is that it should show the "Name is required." error message for both fields when the input is blank. But I only see it for the 2nd field (which is not using my common component).

[image]

I have created a working example in StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-yph1vt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: It appears that the ng-invalid class is not added on the input. The component doesn't know MatError, if you change the tag to `<p>` or something it is there. And the necessary scss for styling the ng-invalid class is not loaded when you manually set it. I'm not sure how to fix it.  But I'm curious and will investigate when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mat-input` inside your `app-common-input` is not bound to any `FormControl`. You're working around it by binding `value`, `onChange` and `onTouched` events to the `<input>`, but none of that actually passes the information about validations and state of the `FormControl` itself.

And the way that `mat-error` works inside of a `mat-form-field`, it needs to know that the bound `FormControl` has some errors to display.

Since what you seem to be looking for is kind of a "pass-through" `ControlValueAccessor`, you can just replace this part:

```
<input
  matInput
  [type]="fieldInfo.type"
  [placeholder]="fieldInfo.placeholder"
  [value]="value"
  (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
  (blur)="onTouched()"
/>
```

with this:

```
<input
  matInput
  [type]="fieldInfo.type"
  [placeholder]="fieldInfo.placeholder"
  [formControl]="ngControl.control"
/>
```

This means that everything that happens to your components will be passed down to the internal `matInput` and vice-versa.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense. I knew I was doing something wrong, but first time working in the new Angular couldn't trace it. So based on that, just a follow-up question. Do I really need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` in `CommonInputComponent`?

Comment: Because I don't really want to implement my own input, I just want to use the `matInput`. And just have a common HTML for label, hints, error messages.

Comment: I think it SHOULD work without implementing `ControlValueAccessor` - just getting the formControl from your component and passing it down to proper place. But I've never done this, so you should check it yourself.